# Loading data from pig to elasticsearch

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-pig, hue, kibana-4

I have a hadoop cluster managed by Cloudera CDH 5.3.

I have ElasticSearch 1.4.4 installed in my master machine(10.44.162.169)

I have downloaded the marvel plugin and so access to my ES via : 
http://10.44.162.169:9200/_plugin/marvel/kibana/index.html#/dashboard/file/marvel.overview.json

I have created an index via sense named myindex with a type named mytype to push my data in it later.

I did also install kibana 4 and changed the kibana.yml like this :

```
# The host to bind the server to
host: "10.44.162.169"

# The Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch_url: "http://10.44.162.169:9200"
```

I access to it via port 5601 (10.44.162.169:5601)

Now I want to load a data I have in my hdfs into my ElasticSearch.

After  dowloading the es-hadoop jar and adding it to the path.

This is how I proceeded :

```
REGISTER /usr/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.0.2/dist/elasticsearch-hadoop-pig-2.0.2.jar

--load the CDR.csv file
cdr= LOAD '/user/omar/CDR.csv' using PigStorage(';')
AS TRAFFIC_TYPE_ID:int,APPELANT:int,CALLED_NUMBER:int,CALL_DURATION:int,LOCATION_NUMBER:chararray,DATE_HEURE_APPEL:chararray);



STORE cdr INTO 'myindex/mytype' USING org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.PigRunner.run('es.nodes'='10.44.162.169');
```

When I execute this; the job is a success !!!

BUT, nothing seems to appear in my ES !

1) When I go and access to marvel, I don't find any documents in myindex !

2 )Neither in my Kibana plugin !

3) Furthermore, when I want to consult the logs in the HUE, I can't find a thing!

- Why data isn't pushed in my ES?
- What should I do to visualize it?
- Why is my created job a success but none log is there to see what's happening!

Any help?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command

```
store cdr INTO 'myindex/mytype' USING org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.EsStorage('es.nodes = localhost:9200');
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know anything about how to use ElasticSearch and Hadoop, but did you try removing the single quotes around the equal sign (=) for the run parameter? i.e.: 'es.nodes=10.44.162.169' instead of 'es.nodes'='10.44.162.169'